# Is there a good children's parsha book that's focused on pshat, not midrash?

Tags: product-recommendation, minor-katan-child, books-generally, tanach, parshanut-torah-comment

Is there a good children's parsha book that's [focused on pshat](http://matzav.com/rav-schachter-teach-the-poshut-pshat), not midrash?

Something like a Little Midrash Says, but based on just the psukim (simple verses), not all the medrish?

Answer (score 4):

For younger children:  [My First Parasha Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006ZN2Q4E)

The 5 volume set is widely distributed.

Authored and copyrighted 1993-1997 by R' Moshe Weissman.  Ill. by Sarah Rothman/Tova Leff.

Published by Bnay Yaakov Pub. 1742 E 7th St. Bkyn, NY 11223 (718) 376-5903.

Comment: How pshat-vs-midrash is this?  For instance, what wrestles with Jacob -- a man or an angel?

Comment: "In the night, Yaakov met an angel.  The angel looked like a man."  It doesn't mention saro shel Esav.  This is probably pshat according to most.

Comment: Do you have any bibliographic information on this book?

Answer (score 4):

If your children are in a school that uses any portion of the Tal-Am Hebrew program, their parshat hashavua books for 3rd-4th-5th grades are superb.  They are keenly aware of the difference between pshat and drash, and in fact their 5th grade book has a section each week that sensitizes kids to the difference between pshat and drash.  The 4th grade book has a question each week on the parsha, presented with 2-3 answers from different commentaries, ranging from Rashi, Ramban, Ibn Ezra to Rav Hirsch and even Da'at Mikra.

Comment: Is this the Tal-Am Hebrew program you're referring to? http://www.talam.org/about.html